# Yii2 checkbox unchecked by default

Tags: yii2

How can I render the checkbox unchecked by default?.
I try this.

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'rememberMe', ['template' => "<div>{input}</div>\n<div>{error}</div>"])->checkbox(['checked'=>false])?>
```

But no way. It allways appends checked="checked" to the html. I need the checkbox to be unchecked for the first time.

Comment: set your attribute in conrtoller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using value = false

```
 <?=$form->field($model, 'rememberMe', 
      ['template' => "<div>{input}</div>\n<div>{error}</div>"])->
     checkbox(['value' => false])?>
```

or (simply) assign  `$model->rememberMe = false;`

Comment: So simple and effective. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is very useful. only need to set true or false.
For example :-

`$model->"CHECKBOX NAME" as true or false`

Simply